# Rdoc, YARD and irb, using intern method on an array?

Tags: ruby, rdoc, yard

I was just trying to generate the documentation for my gem, and upon running either rdoc or yard I got the error

```
undefined method `intern' for []:Array
```

What is going on? I've trying reinstalling everything, and I'm on ruby 2.3.1. Also, from what I understand you can't use intern on an array, so why would rdoc and yard be trying to do that?

**Edit**

I've now investigated further, and it has something to do with my specific syntax, because my setup works on other files, just not mine. How can I check which file has the syntax issue?

RDoc Full Stack Trace (It seems identical to the YARD trace, but I've included both):

```
error generating : Error while evaluating /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/template/darkfish/page.rhtml: undefined method `intern' for []:Array (RDoc::Error)
/home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:15678:in `_CodeFence'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:470:in `apply'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:902:in `_Block'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:470:in `apply'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:856:in `_Doc'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:470:in `apply'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:834:in `_root'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:470:in `apply'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:372:in `parse'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:780:in `parse'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:611:in `parse'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/text.rb:143:in `parse'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/comment.rb:181:in `parse'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/text.rb:137:in `parse'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/template/darkfish/_sidebar_table_of_contents.rhtml:6:in `block in generate_page'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `eval'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `result'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/darkfish.rb:678:in `render'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/template/darkfish/page.rhtml:33:in `block in generate_page'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `eval'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/erb.rb:864:in `result'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/darkfish.rb:725:in `template_result'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/darkfish.rb:704:in `block in render_template'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/darkfish.rb:699:in `open'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/darkfish.rb:699:in `open'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/darkfish.rb:699:in `render_template'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/darkfish.rb:467:in `generate_page'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/darkfish.rb:407:in `block in generate_file_files'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/darkfish.rb:403:in `each'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/darkfish.rb:403:in `generate_file_files'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/generator/darkfish.rb:246:in `generate'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:534:in `block in generate'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:529:in `chdir'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:529:in `generate'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:512:in `document'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/bin/rdoc:20:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rdoc:23:in `load'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rdoc:23:in `<main>'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

YARD Full Stack Trace:

```
/home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:15678:in `_CodeFence': undefined method `intern' for []:Array (NoMethodError)
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:470:in `apply'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:902:in `_Block'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:470:in `apply'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:856:in `_Doc'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:470:in `apply'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:834:in `_root'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:470:in `apply'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:372:in `parse'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/rdoc-4.2.2/lib/rdoc/markdown.rb:780:in `parse'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/helpers/markup/rdoc_markdown.rb:14:in `initialize'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/helpers/html_helper.rb:67:in `new'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/helpers/html_helper.rb:67:in `html_markup_markdown'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/helpers/html_helper.rb:41:in `htmlify'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/templates/default/layout/html/setup.rb:65:in `diskfile'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:355:in `render_section'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:251:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:248:in `each'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:248:in `block in run'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:386:in `add_options'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:247:in `run'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:269:in `block in yieldall'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:400:in `with_section'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:269:in `yieldall'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/templates/default/layout/html/layout.erb:23:in `_erb_cache_5'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:279:in `erb'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/templates/default/layout/html/setup.rb:60:in `layout'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:355:in `render_section'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:251:in `block (2 levels) in run'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:248:in `each'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:248:in `block in run'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:386:in `add_options'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:247:in `run'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:135:in `run'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/templates/default/fulldoc/html/setup.rb:51:in `block in serialize_index'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/engine.rb:122:in `block in with_serializer'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/logging.rb:70:in `capture'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/engine.rb:120:in `with_serializer'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/templates/default/fulldoc/html/setup.rb:50:in `serialize_index'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/templates/default/fulldoc/html/setup.rb:67:in `serialize_file'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/templates/default/fulldoc/html/setup.rb:10:in `block in init'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/templates/default/fulldoc/html/setup.rb:9:in `each'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/templates/default/fulldoc/html/setup.rb:9:in `each_with_index'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/templates/default/fulldoc/html/setup.rb:9:in `init'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:185:in `initialize'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:130:in `new'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/template.rb:135:in `run'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/templates/engine.rb:104:in `generate'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/cli/yardoc.rb:346:in `run_generate'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/cli/yardoc.rb:260:in `run'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/cli/command.rb:13:in `run'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/cli/command_parser.rb:71:in `run'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/lib/yard/cli/command_parser.rb:53:in `run'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/yard-0.9.5/bin/yard:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/yard:23:in `load'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/yard:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/isaiah/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Comment: do you have a longer stack trace or is that it?

Comment: @maxpleaner I've added the full stack traces for both rdoc and yard.

Comment: wierd, are you sure you're using the up-to-date version corresponding to your documentation syntax? Other than that I can't really help you.

Comment: @maxpleaner You can see the version numbers of my stuff in the trace.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Wow @thesecretmaster I can't believe that you'd be so dumb to not realize that it was an issue with a specific piece of syntax that you used in README.md. It's about time that you opened [an issue](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/issues/417) on the rdoc github page.